# Ubuntu server not geting ip and not detecting enp1s0

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ethernet

I have Ubuntu server installed on my laptop and when it boots it doesn't enp1s0 interface doesn't get detected and it doesn't connect to lan. /etc/network/interfaces file doesn't exist. I can temporarily get IP and connect to the internet with **sudo dhclinet**

Comment: Are you sure the interface doesn't get detected? dhclient can't exactly work without a working interface...

Comment: when I boot and run ifconfig it doesn't show but when I run sudo dhclient it shows

Comment: No, that's actually because ifconfig doesn't show _disabled_ interfaces. If dhclient works, that means it's detected just fine and you'll see it in `ip link` or `ifconfig -a`.

Comment: it shows enp1s0 but it doesn't get IP